# How to display the Thunderbird on the menu

Tags: thunderbird, nixos

I'm using "NixOS KDE 16.09".
I installed Thunderbird, but it does not appear in the menu.
Please tell me how to display the Thunderbird on the menu.

Comment: Wondering if this might be an issue with caching menu list. Does logging out and then back in solve this? /me is no kde expert, but i've seen this problem with gnome3+nixos

Comment: Can you edit your question with the result of the following commands: `echo $XDG_DATA_DIRS` and `which thunderbird`?

Comment: By the way, do you still have this problem? Your comment here https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/19295#issuecomment-251934116 seems to indicate that Thunderbird has finally appeared in the menu. Is that correct?

Comment: This problem was able to be resolved.
Thank you.